# Error on installing backpack for laravel 6.0.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laragon

I did a fresh `Laravel 6.0.3` install on laragon and I am trying to install `backpack`.
I did

```sh
composer require backpack/crud correclty
```

but then when I tried to do the next step

```sh
php artisan backpack:base:install
```

I get an error

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException  : The command "composer require backpack/generators --dev" failed.
>   Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins)

I tried to delete the cache, to add `timeout 600` and I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

There was indeed a problem with installing backpack/generators - composer did not fall back to an appropriate version, but it is now fixed. You should be able to run `php artisan backpack:base:install` without problems.

If you hit any roadblocks during the installation, I recommend you follow the [manual installation procedure](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/base-how-to#manually-install-backpack-base), instead of `php artisan backpack:base:install`.

Answer (score 0):

Backpack v3.4 is a collection of packages for Laravel 5.5 / 5.6.

Right under requirement in [Backpack.io](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs#section-requirements) it says it requires laravel 5.5 or 5.6 and PHP7.

It's not compatible with laravel 6.*

Comment: You sure? [take a look](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Base/blob/master/composer.json#L21)

Comment: Looks like they created a [new website](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/introduction)

Comment: @adam yop seems so.

Comment: Ugh. Can't believe that old docs on readme.io are still catching and confusing users. Indeed, we've been rolling our own docs for 2 years I think. Just deleted the readme.io page for good. I hope Google will send people to the right place now. All our links point to the "new" docs, it was just Google that kept thinking highly of the old docs.